# Determine if LU decomposition is possible on a matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, matrix-decomposition, lu-decomposition

I am trying to understand how you determine if LU decomposition is possible on a given matrix. I believe the way to calculate this is to check if the leading-matrices have non-zero determinants. I have performed the calculations for the matrix below to determine if we can utilise LU decomposition. I am wondering if someone can confirm if this is the correct way of determining if LU decomposition can be used on the given matrix.

\begin{equation}
    A=
        \left[ {
            \begin{array}{ccc}
                5 & 6 & 2.3 & 6\\
                9 & 2 & 3.5 & 7\\
               3.5 & 6 & 2 & 3\\
               1.5 & 2 & 1.5 & 6\\
            \end{array} }
        \right]
\end{equation}

Determine if LU decomposition is possible by checking determinant of leading submatrices are not $0$

\begin{equation} A_1 = 5 \end{equation}
\begin{equation}
    A_2=
        \left[ {
            \begin{array}{ccc}
                5 & 6 \\
                9 & 2 \\
            \end{array} }
        \right] = |A_2| = (5*2) - (6*9) = -44
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
    A_3=
        \left[ {
            \begin{array}{ccc}
                5 & 6 & 2.3 \\
                9 & 2 & 3.5 \\
                3.3 & 6 & 2 \\
            \end{array} }
        \right] = |A_3| = -14.68
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
    |A_4|= 5
        \left[ {
            \begin{array}{ccc}
                2 & 3.5 & 7 \\
                6 & 2 & 3 \\
                2 & 1.5 & 6  \\
            \end{array} }
        \right], -6
        \left[ {
            \begin{array}{ccc}
                9 & 3.5 & 7 \\
                3.5 & 2 & 3 \\
                1.5 & 1.5 & 6 \\
            \end{array} }
        \right], 2.3
        \left[ {
            \begin{array}{ccc}
                9 & 2 & 7 \\
                3.5 & 6 & 3 \\
                1.5 & 2 & 6 \\
            \end{array} }
        \right], -6
        \left[ {
            \begin{array}{ccc}
                9 & 2 & 3.5 \\
                3.5 & 6 & 2 \\
                1.5 & 2 & 1.5 \\
            \end{array} }
        \right] = 116.1
\end{equation}

In this instance, since none of the leading matricies have a determinant of $0$ this would be a valid matrix to perform LU decomposition on?

Comment: You will also need to check that the matrix $A$ is invertible, and you will be all set.

Comment: @KBS Thanks for the reply! At the bottom I calculated the determinant of matrix A denoted as $|A_4|$ since this would be the whole of $A$? and it was not 0. This would be checking invertible?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Then, it's fine. If a matrix $A$ is invertible, then it admits an LU factorization if and only if all its leading principal minors are nonzero.

Comment: @KBS Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $A$ is an $n \times n$ real nonsingular matrix.

If all the $k \times k$ principal minors $A_k$, ($k = 1, 2, \ldots, n$)
of $A$ are non-singular, then $A$ has a $LU$-decomposition
$$
A = L U
$$  where $L$ is lower-triangular and $U$ is upper-triangular.

In this $LU$ decomposition of $A$, $L$ is unique if we demand that the diagonal elements of $L$ consist of all $1$'s, *i.e.*
$\mbox{diag}(L) = (1, 1, \ldots, 1)$.

For the given matrix $A$,

$A_1 = 5 \neq 0$.

$A_2 = -44 \neq 0$.

$A_3 = -11.4 \neq 0$.

$A_4 = \mbox{det}(A) = -116.1 \neq 0$.

Thus, $A$ has a $LU$ factorization which can be easily computed as in the Gaussian elimination procedure.